# Automatically suspend luks volume after delay

Tags: luks, cryptsetup

Anyone have any ideas for how I can automatically do a `luksSuspend` on a luks volume after it's been unused for a certain amount of time. I was thinking of just scheduling a command with `crontab` or something, but I don't want it to suspend if I'm actually using the volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent of `luksSetup` is to be used when the device is still in use, but you want to temporarily lock all accesses to it until the passphrase is entered from an external source. Thus it doesn't make much sense to only call `luksSetup` when the device is unused: if it's unused, close it with `luksClose`.

There's no way to atomically enforce that the device is not in use and call `luksSuspend`. What you can do if you really want to suspend the device but only if it isn't in use is call `luksSuspend`, then check with `fuser` or `lsof` for any mounted file on the filesystem that's on the encrypted device; if the filesystem is in use, call `luksResume` immediately. That does have a small chance of requiring you to enter the passphrase.

To detect whether a filesystem is idle, I recommend to piggyback on an existing automounter such as autofs.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out a set of scripts that are working reasonably well, but still looking for other suggestions if anyone has any.

What I've done is to write one script that suspends the luks volume, one that sends a `wall` message, alerting all users (at terminals) that it's about to be suspended, and one that tells it to keep it open (by writing to a file at a reserved path in `/var/run`). I used cron to run the auto-suspend script every half hour, and the "alert" script 2 minutes before that (it only issues the alert if the volume is actually open). If anyone is interested in these scripts, I can post them, or at least more details about them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `lsof` to determine if there are any running processes and passing the PIDs to `pidstat` to analyze IO. From there, we will know whether or not it is safe and desirable to suspend based on what if any processes are accessing the LUKS volume's underlying filesystem.

This would allow you to confidently schedule the script without worry of corruption or processes handling the suspend in an unexpected manner.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! $1 ] ; then
  echo "Usage: $0 device-path"
  exit 1
fi

DEVICE=$1

# Collect PIDs that are running on LUKS filesystem
pids=$(lsof $DEVICE | tail -n+2 | awk '{ print $2 }')

SUSPEND=1
if [ "$pids" ] ; then
  # Get the IO statistics of each process running from LUKS device
  pidactivity=$(echo -E "$pids" | tr "\n" "," | xargs pidstat -d -p)

  # Pull out only the IO fields of the pidstat response
  pidio=$(echo -E "$pidactivity" | tail -n+4 | awk '{ print $5 " " $6 }')

  # If there is IO going on for any of these PIDs, we should suspend
  for io in "$pidio" ; do
    for stat in $io ; do
      if [ `echo "$stat > 0" | bc` -gt 0 ] ; then
        SUSPEND=0
        break 2
      fi
    done
  done
fi

if [ $SUSPEND -eq 1 ] ; then
  cryptsetup luksSuspend $DEVICE
fi
```